# Is string concatenation in scala as costly as it is in Java?

Tags: scala, string-concatenation

In Java, it's a common best practice to do string concatenation with StringBuilder due to the poor performance of appending strings using the + operator. Is the same practice recommended for Scala or has the language improved on how java performs its string concatenation?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Scala uses Java strings (`java.lang.String`), so its string concatenation is the same as Java's: the same thing is taking place in both. (The runtime is the same, after all.) There is a special `StringBuilder` class in Scala, that "provides an API compatible with `java.lang.StringBuilder`"; see http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.5/scala/StringBuilder.html.

But in terms of "best practices", I think most people would generally consider it better to write simple, clear code than maximally efficient code, except when there's an actual performance problem or a good reason to expect one. The `+` operator doesn't really have "poor performance", it's just that `s += "foo"` is equivalent to `s = s + "foo"` (i.e. it creates a new `String` object), which means that, if you're doing a lot of concatenations to (what looks like) "a single string", you can avoid creating unnecessary objects — and repeatedly recopying earlier portions from one string to another — by using a `StringBuilder` instead of a `String`. Usually the difference is not important. (Of course, "simple, clear code" is slightly contradictory: using `+=` is simpler, using `StringBuilder` is clearer. But still, the decision should usually be based on code-writing considerations rather than minor performance considerations.)

Comment: In my case I'm very concerned about performance hence why I'm asking the question. Thanks for all the info!

Comment: AFAIK, the JVM automatically treats repeated '+' concatenations in an expression the same way as it would do a stringbuffer. So there's no performance difference really.

Comment: @aishwarya: The JLS recommends that compilers optimize `foo + bar + baz + bip` to the equivalent of `new StringBuilder(foo).append(bar).append(baz).append(bip).toString()` and `"foo" + "bar" + "baz" + "bip"` to `"foobarbazbip"`, but those are pretty narrow cases. And I don't think JVMs (as opposed to compilers) generally do any sort of optimization along those lines, though I could be wrong.

Comment: pet peeve: using + in a loop results in O(n^2) complexity, while using a StringBuilder in O(n). The extra objects are a minor problem; the explosion in complexity is a major one.

Comment: @PhilipPotter: Good point. I've edited my answer to mention that `StringBuilder` also helps avoid "repeatedly recopying earlier portions from one string to another".

Answer (score 21):

Scalas String concatenation works the same way as Javas does.

```
val x = 5
"a"+"b"+x+"c"
```

is translated to

```
new StringBuilder()).append("ab").append(BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(x)).append("c").toString()
```

StringBuilder is [scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder). That's the reason why the value appended to the StringBuilder is boxed by the compiler.

You can check the behavior by decompile the bytecode with javap.

Answer (score 6):

I want to add: if you have a sequence of strings, then there is already a method to create a new string out of them (all items, concatenated). It's called `mkString`.

Example: (http://ideone.com/QJhkAG)

```
val example = Seq("11111", "2222", "333", "444444")
val result = example.mkString
println(result) // prints "111112222333444444"
```

Answer (score 2):

Scala uses `java.lang.String` as the type for strings, so it is subject to the same characteristics.