# Stack Overflow while processing several columns with a UDF

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a `DataFrame` with many columns of `str` type, and I want to apply a function to all those columns, without renaming their names or adding more columns, I tried using a `for-in` loop executing `withColumn` (see example bellow), but normally when I run the code, it shows a `Stack Overflow` (it rarely works), this `DataFrame` is not big at all, it has just ~15000 records.

```
# df is a DataFrame
def lowerCase(string):
    return string.strip().lower()

lowerCaseUDF = udf(lowerCase, StringType())

for (columnName, kind) in df.dtypes:
    if(kind == "string"):
        df = df.withColumn(columnName, lowerCaseUDF(df[columnName]))

df.select("Tipo_unidad").distinct().show()
```

The complete error is very long, therefore I decided to paste only some lines. But you can find the full trace here [Complete Trace](https://gist.github.com/Bonsanto/c4a73e5b31e1abe65600)

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o516.showString. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 1 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3
>   in stage 2.0 (TID 38, worker2.mcbo.mood.com.ve):
>   java.lang.StackOverflowError  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2774)

I am thinking that this problem is produced because this code launches many jobs (one for each column of type `string`), could you show me another alternative or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How many columns do you have?

Comment: @eliasah around 136, I think that they aren't too many

Comment: I think the loop is keeping the dataframe in memory each time you are computing on it and the GC doesn't have time to clean it thus no memory => SO

Comment: @eliasah It's very probable, but I don't have any other user friendly alternative (the other one will be to do this manually column by column)

Comment: Could you try to use a single select instead? This SO smells like some kind of issue with growing lineage. Also I wouldn't use UDF here. It is kind of wasteful and can be handled directly on internal representation.

Comment: @zero323 that was exactly my point !

Comment: @zero323 Excuse me, but I didn't understand exactly what you mean saying "try to use a single select", I tried one select on the end (that's what shows the error)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lower, trim

exprs = [
    lower(trim(col(c))).alias(c) if t == "string" else col(c) 
    for (c, t) in df.dtypes
]

df.select(*exprs)
```

This approach has two main advantages over you current solution:

- it requires only as single projection (no growing lineage which most likely responsible for SO) instead of projection per string column.
- it operates directly only an internal representation without passing data to Python (`BatchPythonProcessing`).

Comment: Worked perfectly, but how would I do if I have to apply a really complex function, in every string column

Comment: Well, pretty much the same way :) If you cannot use expression (in 1.6 Spark it shouldn't be a problem - there is enough to choose so you can create arbitrary complex transformation) just replace `lower ∘ trim`  with an UDF.