# Creating Pyspark DataFrame column that coalesces two other Columns, why am I getting error of 'unicode' object has no attribute isNull?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm having some trouble with a Pyspark Dataframe.  Specifically, I'm trying to create a column for a dataframe, which is a result of coalescing two columns of the dataframe.

E.g.

```
this_dataframe = this_dataframe.withColumn('new_max_price', coalesce(this_dataframe['max_price'],this_dataframe['avg(max_price)']).cast(FloatType()))
```

The problem with this code is that it still returns values of "null" in certain rows.  Specifically I'm running this code:

```
this_dataset.where(col("new_max_price").isNull()).count()
```

This code gives positive results.  So, while this code works, it does not produce intended results.

I found some other questions (such as [Selecting values from non-null columns in a PySpark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36179330/selecting-values-from-non-null-columns-in-a-pyspark-dataframe)) that were asked that were similar, but for some reason I'm unable to replicate their results.

Here's some code that I have that is based on the aforementioned link:

```
def coalesce_columns(c1, c2):
    if c1 != None and c2 != None:
        return c1
    elif c1 == None:
        return c2
    else:
        return c1

coalesceUDF = udf(coalesce_columns)
max_price_col = [coalesceUDF(col("max_price"), col("avg(max_price)")).alias("competitive_max_price")]
this_dataset.select(max_price_col).show()
```

When I try to execute the last line to test that my results are correct I receive an error.

> AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'isNull'

So basically the question is, how can I use a spark sql function to create a column that is the result of coalescing two pyspark dataframe columns?  If this is impossible, what kind of UDF can I use  in order to create some dataframe column that I can append to another dataframe?

Comment: No `isNull` in your code. Double check if this is really what you use.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think that `coalesce` is actually doing its work and the root of the problem is that you have `null` values in both columns resulting in a `null` after coalescing. I give you an example that may help you.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

data = [Row(a="3.07",b="3.05"),
        Row(a="3.06",b="3.06"),
        Row(a="3.09",b=None),
        Row(a=None,b=None),
        Row(a=None,b="3.06"),
        Row(a=None,b=None)
       ]

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data)

tmp = df.withColumn('c', coalesce(df['a'],df['b']).cast(FloatType()))

tmp.where(col("c").isNotNull()).show()


+----+----+----+
|   a|   b|   c|
+----+----+----+
|3.07|3.05|3.07|
|3.06|3.06|3.06|
|3.09|null|3.09|
|null|3.06|3.06|
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: I have another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344250/spark-assign-value-if-null-to-column-python thanks in advance!