# PySpark SQL: consolidating .withColumn calls

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an RDD that I've converted into a Spark SQL DataFrame.  I want to do a number of transformations of columns with UDFs, which ends up looking something like this:

```
df = df.withColumn("col1", udf1(df.col1))\
       .withColumn("col2", udf2(df.col2))\
       ...
       ...
       .withColumn("newcol", udf(df.oldcol1, df.oldcol2))\
       .drop(df.oldcol1).drop(df.oldcol2)\
       ...
```

etc.

Is there is a more concise way to express this (both the repeated `withColumn` and `drop` calls)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass several operations in one expression.

```py
exprs = [udf1(col("col1")).alias("col1"),
         udf2(col("col2")).alias("col2"),
         ...
         udfn(col("coln")).alias("coln")]
```

And then unpack them inside a `select`:

```py
df = df.select(*exprs)
```

So, taking this approach you will execute such `udfs` over your `df` and you will rename the resulting columns. Note that my answer is almost exactly like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35066231/stack-overflow-while-processing-several-columns-with-a-udf), however the question was totally different from mine, so this is why I decided to answer it and not flag it as duplicate.