# How to use a Scala class inside Pyspark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've been searching for a while if there is any way to use a `Scala` class in `Pyspark`, and I haven't found any documentation nor guide about this subject.

Let's say I create a simple class in `Scala` that uses some libraries of `apache-spark`, something like:

```
class SimpleClass(sqlContext: SQLContext, df: DataFrame, column: String) {
  def exe(): DataFrame = {
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    df.select(col(column))
  }
}
```

- Is there any possible way to use this class in `Pyspark`?
- Is it too tough?
- Do I have to create a `.py` file?
- Is there any guide that shows how to do that?

By the way I also looked at the `spark` code and I felt a bit lost, and I was incapable of replicating their functionality for my own purpose.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes it is possible although can be far from trivial. Typically you want a Java (friendly) wrapper so you don't have to deal with Scala features which cannot be easily expressed using plain Java and as a result don't play well with Py4J gateway.

Assuming your class is int the package `com.example` and have Python `DataFrame` called `df`

```
df = ... # Python DataFrame
```

you'll have to:

1. Build a jar using [your favorite build tool](http://www.scala-sbt.org/).
2. Include it in the driver classpath for example using `--driver-class-path` argument for PySpark shell / `spark-submit`. Depending on the exact code you may have to pass it using `--jars` as well
3. Extract JVM instance from a Python `SparkContext` instance:

   ```
   jvm = sc._jvm
   ```
4. Extract Scala `SQLContext` from a `SQLContext` instance:

   ```
   ssqlContext = sqlContext._ssql_ctx
   ```
5. Extract Java `DataFrame` from the `df`:

   ```
   jdf = df._jdf
   ```
6. Create new instance of `SimpleClass`:

   ```
   simpleObject = jvm.com.example.SimpleClass(ssqlContext, jdf, "v")
   ```
7. Call`exe` method and wrap the result using Python `DataFrame`:

   ```
   from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

   DataFrame(simpleObject.exe(), ssqlContext)
   ```

The result should be a valid PySpark `DataFrame`. You can of course combine all the steps into a single call.

**Important**: This approach is possible only if Python code is executed solely on the driver. It cannot be used inside Python action or transformation. See [How to use Java/Scala function from an action or a transformation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31684842/1560062) for details.

Comment: What happen if the scala class has also alternative constructors? Is it supposed to work?

Answer (score 5):

As an update to [@zero323](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1560062/zero323)'s answer, given that Spark's APIs have evolved over the last six years, a recipe that works in Spark-3.2 is as follows:

1. Compile your Scala code into a JAR file (e.g. using `sbt assembly`)
2. Include the JAR file in the `--jars` argument to `spark-submit` together with any `--py-files` arguments needed for local package definitions
3. Extract the JVM instance within Python:

```
jvm = spark._jvm
```

4. Extract a Java representation of the `SparkSession`:

```
jSess = spark._jsparkSession
```

5. Extract the Java handle for the PySpark `DataFrame` "df" that you want to pass into the Scala method:

```
jdf = df._jdf
```

6. Create a new instance of `SimpleClass` from within PySpark:

```
simpleObject = jvm.com.example.SimpleClass(jSess, jdf, "v")
```

7. Call the `exe` method and convert its output into a PySpark `DataFrame`:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

result = DataFrame(simpleObject.exe(), spark)
```

If you need to pass additional parameters, such as a Python dictionary, PySpark may automatically convert them into corresponding **Java** types they before emerge into your Scala methods. Scala provides the [`JavaConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.16/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html) package to help with translating this into more natural Scala datatypes. For example, a Python dictionary could be passed into a Scala method and immediately converted from a Java HashMap into a Scala (mutable) Map:

```
def processDict(spark: SparkSession, jparams: java.util.Map[String, Any]) {
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
  val params = jparams.asScala
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. But how to do type conversion when pass parameters?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. But how to do type conversion when pass parameters? For example, I have a Scala class with a method like 

read(paraA: String, paraB: Map[String, String]) When I call the method like

read("abc", {"cde":"fgh"})

, it gave me the following error: 

Method read([class java.lang.String, class java.util.HashMap]) does not exist.

I guess it is because a python dictionary is converted as HashMap, but the original method required a Scala Immuted Map?

Comment: Thanks, Gary - I've added an example of how you might be able to do this.

Comment: Thank you @rwp for providing an updated Spark API answer.   Can you please elaborate in step 5, where `df` is defined?  Is it in `scala` or `python`?  I am having difficulties following your step trying to understand what steps are done in which `runtime stack`.  TIA!

Comment: Thanks, @geekyj - I've amended the description to try to make it clearer that "df" is whatever dataframe you want to pass into your Scala library, and that this step is executed within PySpark rather than Scala Spark.