# Write PySpark Dataframe to SQL DB as batch

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a dataframe in PySpark (using Databricks) and I want to write this dataframe to a SQL DB (Azure SQL Database in my case). This works fine except that it seems that this triggers a row-by-row insert into the SQL DB which is of course not feasible for 10M+ rows.
Is there any way to force PySpark to use Bulk-Inserts instead?

currently I simply use this command:

`df.write.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=targetTable, mode="append", properties=connectionProperties)`

The code that gets executed on the SQL side looks like this:

`(@P0 int,@P1 bit,@P2 bit,@P3 float,@P4 float,@P5 nvarchar(4000),@P6 int,@P7 int,@P8 int)INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable("Index","Sampling10pct","Sampling1pct","Latitude","Longitude","SessionID","Year","Month","Day") VALUES (@P0,@P1,@P2,@P3,@P4,@P5,@P6,@P7,@P8)`

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sqldb-spark

Comment: thanks, that basically answers my question
I just need to use Scala then instead of Python which is OK

Comment: The API is not very complex, so it shouldn't require much effort to use it from PySpark (https://stackoverflow.com/q/36023860/8371915)