# 'KafkaDStream' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, stream-processing

I'm try to connect Kafak Topic which use Avro to Spark Stream.
I try bellow code:

```
schema_registry_client = CachedSchemaRegistryClient(url='schema_registry_url')
serializer = MessageSerializer(schema_registry_client)

def decoder(s):
    decoded_message = serializer .decode_message(s)
    return decoded_message


kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, topic, {'bootstrap.servers': brokers}, valueDecoder=decoder)
```

However i got bellow error when i ran this:

> 'Kafka DStream' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

How can we overcome this?

Comment: Could try a different way to read Avro https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS

Comment: @cricket_007, Thank for your suggestion, But ABRiS only support for Scala isn't it?

Comment: It's all Java code... You're already importing `CachedSchemaRegistryClient`, which is also a Java class.

Comment: Sorry my bad, Sins examples are written in Scala, I was confused. Sorry again

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I didn't realize you're importing confluent-kafka python code... See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36023860/how-to-use-a-scala-class-inside-pyspark