# Convert Java object to python in py4j

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, pyspark, py4j

I have a spark Scala library and I am building a python wrapper on top of it. One class of my library provides the following method

```
package com.example
class F {
  def transform(df: DataFrame): DataFrame
}
```

and I am using py4j in the following way to create a wrapper for `F`

```
def F():
return SparkContext.getOrCreate()._jvm.com.example.F()
```

which allows me to call the method `transform`

The problem is that the python Dataframe object is obviously different from the Java Dataframe object. For this purpose, I need a way to convert a python df to a java one, for which I use the following code from py4j docs

```
class DataframeConverter(object):
def can_convert(self, object):
    from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame
    return isinstance(object, DataFrame)

def convert(self, object, gateway_client):
    from pyspark.ml.common import _py2java
    return _py2java(SparkContext.getOrCreate(), object)

protocol.register_input_converter(DataframeConverter())
```

My problem is that now I want to do the inverse: getting a java dataframe from the `transform` and continue to use it in python. I tried to use `protocol.register_output_converter` but I couldn't find any useful example, apart for code dealing with java collections.

How can I do that? An obvious solution would be to create a python class `F` which defines all methods present in java `F`, forwards all the python calls to the jvm, get back the result and convert it accordingly. This approach works but it implies that I have to redefine all methods of `F` thus generating code duplication and a lot more maintainance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a Scala class inside Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36023860/how-to-use-a-scala-class-inside-pyspark)

Comment: my question is how to register this behaviour automatically, instead of manually writing the df transformation in input/output