# Modify a struct column in Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, struct, apache-spark-sql, schema

I have a PySpark dataframe which contains a column "student" as follows:

```
"student" : {
   "name" : "kaleem",
   "rollno" : "12"
}
```

Schema for this in dataframe is:

```
structType(List(
   name: String, 
   rollno: String))
```

I need to modify this column as

```
"student" : {
   "student_details" : {
         "name" : "kaleem",
         "rollno" : "12"
   }
}
```

Schema for this in dataframe must be:

```
structType(List(
  student_details: 
     structType(List(
         name: String, 
         rollno: String))
))
```

How to do this in Spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [named_struct](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#named_struct) function to achieve this

**1. Read the json as column**

```scala
val  data =
      """
        | {
        |   "student": {
        |       "name": "kaleem",
        |       "rollno": "12"
        |   }
        |}
      """.stripMargin
    val df = spark.read.json(Seq(data).toDS())
    df.show(false)
    println(df.schema("student"))
```

Output

```
+------------+
|student     |
+------------+
|[kaleem, 12]|
+------------+

StructField(student,StructType(StructField(name,StringType,true), StructField(rollno,StringType,true)),true)
```

**2. change the schema using `named_struct`**

```scala
val processedDf = df.withColumn("student",
      expr("named_struct('student_details', student)")
    )
    processedDf.show(false)
    println(processedDf.schema("student"))
```

Output

```
+--------------+
|student       |
+--------------+
|[[kaleem, 12]]|
+--------------+

StructField(student,StructType(StructField(student_details,StructType(StructField(name,StringType,true), StructField(rollno,StringType,true)),true)),false)
```

> For python `step#2` will work as is just remove val

Answer (score 2):

With a library called [spark-hats](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/spark-hats) - This library extends Spark DataFrame API with helpers for transforming fields inside nested structures and arrays of arbitrary levels of nesting., you can do a lot of these transformations.

```scala
scala> import za.co.absa.spark.hats.Extensions._

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)

scala> val df2 = df.nestedMapColumn("ID", "ID", c => struct(c as alfa))

scala> df2.printSchema
root
 |-- ID: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- alfa: string (nullable = true)

scala> val df3 = df2.nestedMapColumn("ID.alfa", "ID.alfa", c => struct(c as "beta"))

scala> df3.printSchema
root
 |-- ID: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- alfa: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- beta: string (nullable = true)
```

Your query would be

```scala
df.nestedMapColumn("student", "student", c => struct(c as "student_details"))
```

Comment: this is scala. what about pyspark?

Comment: Using scala libraries in pyspark is quite common. Look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36024707/5594180) or other articles [1](https://diogoalexandrefranco.github.io/scala-code-in-pyspark/), [2](https://aseigneurin.github.io/2016/09/01/spark-calling-scala-code-from-pyspark.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Spark 3.1+**

To modify struct type columns, we can use [**`withField`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.withField.html#pyspark.sql.Column.withField) and [**`dropFields`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.dropFields.html#pyspark.sql.Column.dropFields)

```scala
F.col("Student").withField("student_details", F.col("student"))
F.col("Student").dropFields("name", "rollno")
```

---

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([(("kaleem", "12"),)], "student struct<name:string,rollno:string>")
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- student: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- rollno: string (nullable = true)
```

Script:

```py
df = df.withColumn("student", F.col("Student")
    .withField("student_details", F.col("student"))
    .dropFields("name", "rollno")
)
```

Result:

```py
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- student: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- student_details: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- rollno: string (nullable = true)
```