# Change schema of spark dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe with column "Student".

One entry of data is as follows:

```
{
   "Student" : {
       "m" : {
           "name" : {"s" : "john"},
           "score": {"s" : "165"}
       }
   }
}
```

I want to change the schema of this column, so that the entry looks as follows:

```
{
    "Student" : 
    {
        "m" : 
        {
            "StudentDetails" : 
            {
                "m" : 
                {
                    "name" : {"s" : "john"},
                    "score": {"s" : "165"}
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

The problem is that the Student field can also be null in the dataframe. So I want to retain the null values but change the schema of not null values.  I have used a udf for the above process which works.

```
        def Helper_ChangeSchema(row):
            #null check
            if row is None:
                return None
            #change schema
            data = row.asDict(True)
            return {"m":{"StudentDetails":data}}
```

but  udf is a black box for spark. Is there any method to do the same using inbuilt spark functions or sql queries.

Comment: What is the difference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62050145/2129801) question?

Comment: {Student:null} can be there as well in the data.

Comment: What is wrong with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62063534/2129801) answer? Why shouldn't it work with null? Btw: why didn't you [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it?

Comment: Yeah cool solution :). But I am struggling to apply this here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works exactly like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62063534/2129801). Just add another nested level in the struct:

Either as SQL expression:

```python
processedDf = df.withColumn("student", F.expr("named_struct('m', named_struct('student_details', student))"))
```

or in Python code using the [struct function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.struct):

```python
processedDf = df.withColumn("student", F.struct(F.struct(F.col("student")).alias('m')))
```

Both versions have the same result:

```
root
 |-- student: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- m: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- student_details: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- m: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- s: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- score: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- s: string (nullable = true)
```

Both approaches work also fine with empty rows. Using this input data

```python
data ='{"student" : {"m" : {"name" : {"s" : "john"},"score": {"s" : "165"}}}}'
data2='{"student": null }'
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([data, data2]))
```

`processedDf.show(truncate=False)` prints

```
+---------------------+
|student              |
+---------------------+
|[[[[[john], [165]]]]]|
|[[]]                 |
+---------------------+
```

---

**EDIT**: if the whole row should be set to null instead of the fields of the struct, you can add a [when](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when)

```python
processedDf = df.withColumn("student", F.when(F.col("student").isNull(), F.lit(None)).otherwise(F.struct(F.struct(F.col("student")).alias('m'))))
```

This will result in the same schema, but a different output for the null row:

```
+---------------------+
|student              |
+---------------------+
|[[[[[john], [165]]]]]|
|null                 |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: Rows can be null as well as empty. This solution will handle empty rows but how will null rows be handled

Comment: I think null rows work fine. I have added my test data.