# Spark DataFrame vs sqlContext

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

For the purposes of comparison, suppose we have a table "T" with two columns "A","B". We also have a hiveContext operating in some HDFS database. We make a data frame:

In theory, which of the following is faster:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT A,SUM(B) FROM T GROUP BY A")
```

or

```
df.groupBy("A").sum("B")
```

where "df" is a dataframe referring to T. For these simple kinds of aggregate operations, is there any reason why one should prefer one method over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark developers have made great effort to optimise. The performance between DataFrame Scala and DataFrame SQL is undistinguishable. Even for DataFrame Python, the differ is when collect data to driver.

> **It opens a new world**
>
> [**It doesn't have to be one vs. another**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464122/spark-performance-for-scala-vs-python)
>
> **We can just choose what ever way we comfortable with**

The performance comparison published by [databricks](http://www.slideshare.net/databricks/spark-sqlsse2015public)
[image]

Answer (score 5):

No, these should boil down to the same execution plan. Underneath the Spark SQL engine is using the same optimization engine, the catalyst optimizer. You can always check this yourself by looking at the spark UI, or even calling `explain` on the resultant DataFrame.